# MA Access SQL statements not working correctly when I try to convert to Mariadb SQL Statement

Tags: ms-access, mariadb

This MS Access Update finds all Duplicate entries and assigns the numerical value to LNCount.  I then can run a query/form against it and do what is necessary to eliminate the dups.

```
UPDATE Exam SET Exam.LNCount = DCount("DUP","Exam","DUP =""" & [DUP] & """")
WHERE (((Exam.Certificate_No) In (SELECT [Certificate_No] FROM [Exam] As Tmp  where [Certificate_No] Not Like "000*" GROUP BY [Certificate_No] HAVING Count(*)>1 )));
```

This works correctly from Access to SQL, but is extremely slow.  It was suggested I make it a stored procedure or run it directly on the SQL server.

To that end...

I tried to convert it to SQL (MariaDB) but it either doesn't work, or works incorrectly.

Try 1:

```
UPDATE Exam Set LNCOUNT = Count(DUP) 
WHERE Certificate_No IN
(SELECT Certificate_No FROM Exam As Tmp  where Certificate_No Not Like "000%" GROUP BY Certificate_No HAVING Count(*)>1 );
```

Result Invalid use of group

Try 2:

```
UPDATE Exam Set LNCOUNT
WHERE Certificate_No IN
(SELECT Certificate_No FROM Exam As Tmp  where Certificate_No Not Like "000%" GROUP BY Certificate_No HAVING Count(*)>1 );
```

Result (Too many to list, let's say its wrong)

Try 3:

```
UPDATE Exam Set LNCOUNT = 

(SELECT Certificate_No FROM Exam As Tmp  where Certificate_No Not Like "000%" GROUP BY Certificate_No HAVING Count(*)>1 );
```

Result: Subquery returns more than 1 row.
I tried adding "IN" before Select, but any field I tried gives me a "Truncated incorrect Decimal Value "099-10141" (that is a Certificate No).  I tried using Count(DUP), Count(DUP) AS X, etc., with all failing for various and sundry reasons.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

I tried adding "IN" before Select, but any field I tried gives me a "Truncated incorrect Decimal Value "099-10141" (that is a Certificate No).  I tried using Count(DUP), Count(DUP) AS X, etc., with all failing for various and sundry reasons.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `UPDATE Exam JOIN ( SELECT Certificate_No, COUNT(DUP) as dup_count FROM Exam WHERE Certificate_No NOT LIKE '000%' GROUP BY Certificate_No HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS tmp ON Exam.Certificate_No = tmp.Certificate_No SET Exam.LNCount = tmp.dup_count`

Comment: Thank you, the response to the update looks like the right answer records.

Appreciated!

Comment: What is Access to SQL? Access runs SQL. Likely you meant converting the dialects Access SQL to MariaDB SQL.

Comment: Tomato/tomato....